puppeteer elementHandle by index or by checking textContent
I have a page similar to this
<div class="myclass">Some Text 1 </div>
<div class="myclass">Some Text 2 </div>
<div class="myclass">Some Text 3 </div>
<div class="myclass">Some Text 4 </div>

I want to get the elementHandle of these in puppeter using
await page.$('.myclass');

But i want to get the element by index, something similarto
await page.$('document.querySelectorAll(\'div[class="myclass"]\')[' +  myIndex ']')

or by checking the textContent (pseudo code)
 await page.$('document.querySelectorAll(\'div[class="myclass"]\').foreach => textContent == Some Text 2')

Is it possible to achieve this with puppeteer nodejs ?

This is two questions in one, and it's best to solve each one separately with existing answers/threads that are quite comprehensive: query by text and query by index. Beyond that, I suggest reading through the docs, since your code misuses page.$. page.$ and page.$$ take a CSS selector as an arg, not a JS expression. If you want to run code in the browser, you need page.$eval, page.$$eval, or page.evaluate.


get element(Handle) by index:

Not many people use this, but my favourite method to get an element by index is by using a build-in css selector: :nth-child()! This is an example (inside an async function, of course):
const index = 2; // second element (nth-child uses 1-based index)
const elementHandle = await page.$(`div.myclass:nth-child(${index})`);

You can't use document.querySelectorAll() inside await page.$(), page.$() expects a selector as argument, see: https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page._

get element(Handle) by text content

Just like I just said, you can only pass a css selector string inside page.$(). I would use the index solution, but if you want to get an element by text content you can use this example that uses page.evaluateHandle():
const textToFind = "Some Text 2";
const elementHandle = await page.evaluateHandle((text) => {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.myclass'))
    .find(element => element.textContent === text);
}, textToFind);

I hope this is helpful for someone! Have a nice day
